# Multiple calls in for yield

Tags: scala, future

I don't understand how can I call my function `doSomething()` on each element  in the `for comprehension` and manage with futures because of the `.map` here.

I'm not sure what about the good way to do this. Is it to not use `for comprehension` with `doSomething()` ?

```
def myFunc(tion(ids: List[Ids]): Future[MyBean] = {
  for {
    first <- ids.map{ id =>
      myDAO.doSomething(id)
    }
    second <- myDAO.doSomehtingElse(ids)
  } yield {
    MyBean(first, second)
  }
}

def doSomething(id: Id): Future[Long] = Future {...}
def doSomethingElse(ids: List[Id]): Future[Long] = Future {...}
```

Comment: If you want to call `doSomeghing` for each id then you would have many `first` values, so does **MyBean** expects a list of futures, or maybe you want to create many **MyBeans**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this line:

```
  ids.map{ id =>
      myDAO.doSomething(id)
    }
```

You will get list of futures `List[Future[A]]`. To be able to flatMap it with another future, you need to convert it to `Future[List[A]]`. To achieve this you can use `Future.sequence`. Also, you can use `Future.traverse`:

```
Future.traverse(ids)(myDao.doSomething)
```

In this case, you can avoid using `map`.

Finally, it can be done as follow:

```
  for {
    first <- Future.sequence(ids.map(id => myDAO.doSomething(id)))
    second <- myDAO.doSomehtingElse(ids)
  } yield {
    MyBean(first, second)
  }
```

Or:

```
      for {
        first <- Future.traverse(ids)(myDAO.doSomething)
        second <- myDAO.doSomehtingElse(ids)
      } yield {
        MyBean(first, second)
  }
```

Also, keep in mind that `myDAO.doSomehtingElse` will be called sequentially - not in parallel.